# String formatting issue when using a function

Tags: python-2.7

I have what I believe to be an embarrassingly simple problem, but three hours of googling and checking stackoverflow have not helped.

Let's say I have a very simple piece of code:

```
def secret_formula(started):
  jelly_beans = started*500
  jars = jelly_beans/1000
  crates = jars/100
  return jelly_beans,jars,crates

start_point = 10000

print("We'd have {} beans, {} jars, and {} crates.".format(secret_formula(start_point)))
```

What happens is I get the "IndexError: tuple index out of range". So I just print the `secret_formula` function to see what it looks like, and it looks like this:

```
(5000000, 5000.0, 50.0)
```

Basically, it is treating the output as one 'thing' (I am still very new, sorry if my language is not correct). My question is, why does it treat it like this and how do I make it pass the three outputs (`jelly_beans`, `jars`, and `crates`) so that it formats the string properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` function of the string take a variable number of argument. The `secret_formula` function is returning a tuple. You want to convert that to a list of arguments. This is done using the following syntax:

```
print("We'd have {} beans, {} jars, and {} crates.".format(*secret_formula(start_point)))
```

The important par is the `*` character. It tell that you want to convert the following iterable into a list of argument to pass to the function.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use the * but I was putting it in the wrong place so I gave up.